# JSF entity converter difficulty

Tags: jsf-2, jpa-2.0, facelets, ejb-3.1, converters

I'm developing on JSF2.1(PF3.5) + EJB(3.1) + JPA(eclipselink2.4.1).
On a facelet i have a form with an input box to search for 'Merchant' entities with ajax.
I need the searched merchant reference to associate with my 'Restaurant' entity, as 'Merchant' is a foreign key on Restaurant.
I can get the searched Merchant values on one form and render those values inside another form input fields for example. I don't know how to transport this Merchant reference along another Restaurant fields i have on this second form. As far as I have access to fields on this Merchant, I think I need an entity converter, but what I've done is not working.
Below, relevant code:

This is the search box, on first form:

```
    <p:inputText value="#{merchantMB.searchValue}" required="true"
        requiredMessage="Pf associe um comerciante ao Restaurante!">
        <f:ajax event="blur" listener="#{merchantMB.search}"
        render="results :restaurantDetailForm:merchantFirstName:restaurantDetailForm:merchantEmail" />
        </p:inputText>
```

Second form, where I can access values from searched entity:

```
<h:outputText value="Nome Comerciante: " />
<p:inputText id="merchantFirstName"
    value="#{merchantMB.searchedMerchant.firstName}" readonly="true">
</p:inputText>

<h:outputText value="Email Comerciante: " />
<p:inputText id="merchantEmail"
    value="#{merchantMB.searchedMerchant.email}" readonly="true">
</p:inputText>
```

In this second form I need to associate searchedMerchant id, as this value is a foreign key to my Restaurant entity.
Also in this form I have access to fields related to Related like this:

```
<h:outputText value="Nome Restaurante: " />
<p:inputText id="name"
    value="#{restaurantMB.selectedRestaurant.name}" required="true"
    requiredMessage="Pf introduza o nome!">
    <p:watermark for="name" value="Nome" />
</p:inputText>
```

How can I submit the searchedMerchantId through Managed Bean(restaurantMB), to associate with it's restaurantMB.selectedRestaurant.merchant.id ?

Here my restaurantMB(relevant part):

```
// Selected restaurant that will be updated
private Restaurant selectedRestaurant;

@PostConstruct
public void init() { //
    newRestaurant = new Restaurant();
    newRestaurant.setDateOfInscriptionAsRestaurant(getCurrentTimeStamp());

    lazyModel = new LazyRestaurantDataModel(das);

    selectedRestaurant = new Restaurant();
    selectedRestaurant.setMerchant(new Merchant());
}
```

and my Restaurant entity(relevant part):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RESTAURANTS")

public class Restaurant extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    /...other stuff.../

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "merchantID")
    private Merchant merchant;  <---------THIS IS THE FK

    /**
     * @return the merchant
     */
    public Merchant getMerchant() {
        return merchant;
    }

    /**
     * @param merchant the merchant to set
     */
    public void setMerchant(Merchant merchant) {
        this.merchant = merchant;
    }

    public Restaurant() {
    }
}
```

I have hashcode and equals on my Merchant entity, and I only have one persisted entity right now.
Do I need an converter? How can I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

I implemented search method inside restaurant managed bean(i also have it inside merchant managed bean, and i was trying to use it); info is stored in one instance of a Merchant and when i'm manipulating an instance of a Restaurant, before persisting changes i set this Restaurant's merchant (Foreign Key).
Below relevant code on my restaurant managed bean.

```
//the merchant to store values searched, used in update
private Merchant searchedMerchant;
private String searchValue;
//the correspondent restaurant-merchant, used in update, and new record
private Merchant merchant;
/**
 * @return the merchant
 */
public Merchant getMerchant() {
    return merchant;
}

/**
 * @param merchant the merchant to set
 */
public void setMerchant(Merchant merchant) {
    this.merchant = merchant;
}

/**
 * @return the searchValue
 */
public String getSearchValue() {
    return searchValue;
}

/**
 * @param searchValue the searchValue to set
 */
public void setSearchValue(String searchValue) {
    this.searchValue = searchValue;
}
/**
 * @return the searchedMerchant
 */
public Merchant getSearchedMerchant() {
    return searchedMerchant;
}

/**
 * @param searchedMerchant the searchedMerchant to set
 */
public void setSearchedMerchant(Merchant searchedMerchant) {
    this.searchedMerchant = searchedMerchant;
}
/**
 * 
 * @param actionEvent
 */
public void doUpdateRestaurant(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    // logger.log(Level.INFO, "doUpdateUser(ActionEvent actionEvent)");
    System.out.println("doUpdateRestaurant(ActionEvent actionEvent): "
            + selectedRestaurant.toString());
    selectedRestaurant.setMerchant(searchedMerchant);<---I was missing this!
    das.update(selectedRestaurant);
}
```